# How to hide features and selectable folders/drives on an OpenFileDialog window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a software for an embedded device running WES7. The application is a standard, .NET 3.5 WinForms project.

The requirement is that users should be able to browse and select specific files from their pendrive, or from network, but not from any locations on system drive. So I'm looking for a solution to hide the links and buttons on the standard OpenFileDialog window somehow, so the users would see only their pendrives if there is any, or network places link.

I was searching already on MSDN and on other forums as well, and I couldn't find any idea until now. If there is no way to get this work with the standard OpenFileDialog, are there any simple custom components out there for browsing files restricted to specified drives or parent folders?

Comment: No.  Use the FileOk event to prevent selections you don't like.

Comment: I know that event, but it's quite ugly solution in this case. Looks like I'll have to implement my own file browser...

Comment: Not saying Hans is wrong but a x-MSFT did it when we worked together on an app, I'll ask him for the code as I'm needing this exact same thing - again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, its as easy as [Customizing Your Open File Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300434.aspx)

> The OpenFileDialog class exposes a set of properties to configure the
>   dialog. For example, you can choose the initial directory, the initial
>   filter index, the title of the window, whether multiple files can be
>   selected, and whether the application's current directory should be
>   restored before closing. The class also fires an event (called FileOk)
>   whenever the user clicks on the Open button.
>
> OpenFileDialog is a sealed class, so you can't derive from it.
>   However, if you want to customize the behavior of a file dialog, to
>   the extent that it is possible, you should create a brand new class
>   deriving from the abstract class FileDialog. In this case, you have
>   access to a couple of powerful but protected methods such as HookProc
>   and RunDialog. HookProc defines the dialog box hook procedure that
>   adds specific functionality to the common dialog....

**Update:**

On Windows 7 PC's it doesn't work. eg:

```
OpenDialogPlaces o = new OpenDialogPlaces();
//o.Places.Add(18);
//o.Places.Add(5);
//o.Places.Add(6);
o.Init();
o.OpenDialog.ShowDialog();
o.Reset();
```

Still shows everything in the left-hand:

[image]

It did work in previous versions of Windows:

[image]

Another thing it appears Microsoft has changed the ComDlg32's location, I tried both places but no luck.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the very late reaction. I've found that article that time, and noticed myself that it doesn't work on Windows 7, nor WES7 (expectadly). At the end I solved the problem with the FilOk event, it was ugly but satisfactory. I'll accpet your answer anyway, because it seems like there's no other solution currently.